# What Prevents Hackers from Pretending To Be A Server/Client With Public Keys In Asymmetric Encryption?

Tags: security, private-key, public-key

In asymmetric encryption, public keys can be used to encrypt messages sent to a device with the matching private key. I understand that this prevents sniffers from knowing the content of a message, but consider this: 
What keeps a hacker from using the public key to encrypt messages and pretend to be someone he\she is not? Say I am shopping on Amazon, and a hacker managed to capture amazon's public key when Amazon exchanged it with me. Couldn't this hacker pretend to be me by simply modifying the headers of his packets to look like they came from my computer? I know this doesn't happen, so what am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean the ssl connection between your browser and the  amazon webserver?

Comment: SSL is asymmetric (it uses a public and private keys), so this question would apply to SSL. If I'm not mistaken, TLS also uses a similar protocol.

Comment: SSL and TLS are the same. SSL is the old name. SSL isn't only asymmetric. It's an hybrid encryption. In the beginnig asymmetric encryption is used to exchange a key for symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a hacker managed to capture amazon's public key

Amazon's public key is public. Everyone knows it. The one that was issued May 3, 2018 begins "A9 F4 4A 9B 29 84 20 A7 53 FF BA 01 B5 1E 0C 2A A7 53". The whole point of public/private key cryptography is that the public key is not a secret. So capturing the public key is not important.

Your question isn't about masquerading as Amazon to you (i.e. having to do with Amazon's keys). It's about masquerading as you to Amazon. That's a completely different situation. You don't identify yourself to Amazon with a certificate (called a "client certificate"), so certificates and public/private key cryptography have nothing to do with this. Yes; anyone could send a message to Amazon encrypted with their public key, but that's not how you prove you are who you say you are.

Instead, you identify yourself to Amazon with credentials, typically a user name and a password. When you do that, Amazon hands you back a session token, which is just a big random number that is mapped to you in a database table (or sometimes the session token is encrypted information about the session so that the database isn't needed). Once you're authenticated, you keep passing your session token back to Amazon to say "you already know and trust who I am."

So what if someone captures the session token? That would be a big deal. That would absolutely allow exactly what you're describing. The session token has to be protected for as long as it's valid. We protect it when we pass it to Amazon using TLS which "prevents sniffers from knowing the content of a message" so attackers hopefully can't discover the session id.

There are many attacks to steal the session id, broadly called "session hijacking." One of the more famous was [Firesheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep), which relied on unsecured (HTTP) sessions. However, there are more advanced attacks against HTTPS, such as [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH). Improvements in TLS have mitigated against various known attacks, but it is always possible that new ones will emerge.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I hadn't considered passwords and usernames. That's what I was missing. Passwords can be sent securely using the server's public key, and if the credentials are valid then a TLS handshake can be done with confidence. Thanks, this answers my question!

Answer (score 2):

> What keeps a hacker from using the public key to encrypt messages and pretend to be someone he\she is not? Say I am shopping on Amazon, and a hacker managed to capture amazon's public key when Amazon exchanged it with me. Couldn't this hacker pretend to be me by simply modifying the headers of his packets to look like they came from my computer?

Very good question.  TLS prevents this by creating sessions keys between the client and server during the handshake protocol.  There are two types of keys: one for encryption (typically AES) and one for [message integrity / message authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MAC) (typically HMAC).  All comms during the session are encrypted with the symmetric encryption key and MAC'ed with the MAC key.  Any data that is not properly signed with the MAC key is not accepted by the server.  Thus, only one who has these keys can communicate with the server for that session.

So the question then reduces to how an attacker can determine the encryption and MAC keys which are set up during the initial TLS handshake.  Note during the handshake, the server provides its public key via the certificate to the client, and the client verifies that the certificate is valid -- including that it belongs to the domain that is claimed in the certificate.  This allows the client to verify that it is talking to the right server assuming nobody can bypass PKI (i.e. cert authorities are doing the right thing and nobody can break the public key crypto).  Now different clients can set up different sessions with the server, but they all are done using a private key generated by each client and uniquely known by each client.  Therefore, each client sets up its session in a unique way using a key that is known only to them and nobody else.

There is more to the whole design if you want to dig deep, including how sequence numbers are used to prevent replay attacks.  But I hope you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the TLS Handshake protocol which states clearly what is happening in TLS: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_Handshake_Protocol

1. You don't have a private or public key when connecting to amazon, because you're not authenticating with a client certificate.
2. If a hacker steals your public key that is not a problem because your public key can only be used to send encrypted messages to **you**. Only **you** can decrypt these messages, because only **you** have the matching private key. That's what asymmetric cryptography is all about!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't mean to say my public key. I updated my post and fixed the typo. I was thinking of amazon's public key. I realize that public keys are only used to encrypt. However, that does not keep a hacker from encrypting a message and sending it to amazon as if it were me. (I'm just using amazon as a hypothetical example, I don't know exactly what protocol amazon specifically uses) What keeps this hacker from sending information such as "add this item to cart" to amazon using amazon's public key?

Comment: Well, I think your question has been answered by the others now :)

Answer (score 0):

> Say I am shopping on Amazon, and a hacker managed to capture amazon's public key when Amazon exchanged it with me.

Data encrypted with Amazon's public key can only be decrypted with Amazon's private key.

Comment: Precisely. All the hacker would need to do is forge a message such as, "add such and such to my cart", encrypt it with amazon's public key, and send it to amazon to be decrypted, (which amazon can do, because only they have the private key, as you pointed out) perhaps editing the packet headers to look like they came from my IP address and were in the range of my session, etc.

Comment: Is there anything keeping a hacker from doing that?

Comment: Yes, it won't work. The attacker needs Amazons public and private keys and some information that's initialized when the connection starts.

Comment: Why would the hacker need Amazons private key? In the classic situation with Bob sending Alice a message encrypted using Alice's public key, couldn't Jack, the third party, just as easily send Alice a message with that same public key? Jack wouldn't need Alice's private key, since it's used to decrypt.

Comment: @CalebBertrand The first step in the TLS comms is to agree on session keys between the end user and the server -- these session keys are used for encryption and for message integrity (typically HMAC algorithm is used).  So every communication from the legitimate client is signed by that message integrity key, which prevents the attacker from injecting other data.  TLS also uses message sequence numbers to prevent replay attacks -- sequence numbers need to increase.

Comment: "Data encrypted with Amazon's public key can only be decrypted with Amazon's private key." -- This is an over simplification.  There are two parts to TLS, one is setting up the session and the other is secure comms during the session.  It is the latter that the poster is asking about, and that has nothing to do with public key crypto.  Public key crypto is only done in the initial handshake that sets up the session.